# Liquidsoap on windows, how to install LADSPA plugin

Tags: liquidsoap

I have the official windows package of liquidsoap-1.0.1
How can I install LADSPA plugin? I tried to put the dll-files of the plugins into "plugin" folder and run --list-plugin, but liquidsoap doesn't read them. thanks